# Python Selecting and Adding row values of columns in dataframe to create an aggregated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to process my dataframe in Python such that I add the numeric values of numeric columns that lie between 2 rows of the dataframe.

The dataframe can be created using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a',0,1,0,0,0,0,'i'],
                            ['b',1,0,0,0,0,0,'j'],
                            ['c',0,0,1,0,0,0,'k'], 
                            ['None',0,0,0,1,0,0,'l'], 
                            ['e',0,0,0,0,1,0,'m'], 
                            ['f',0,1,0,0,0,0,'n'], 
                            ['None',0,0,0,1,0,0,'o'], 
                            ['h',0,0,0,0,1,0,'p']]),
                            columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                            index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

[image: input dataframe]

I need to add all rows that occur before the 'None' entries and move the aggregated row to a new dataframe that should look like:

[image: output dataframe]

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data frame dtype is mess up , cause you are using the array to assign the value , since one array only accpet one type , so it push all int to become string , we need convert it firstly

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors ='ignore')# convert

df['newkey']=df[0].eq('None').cumsum()# using cumsum create the key 
df.loc[df[0].ne('None'),:].groupby('newkey').agg(lambda x : x.sum() if x.dtype=='int64' else x.head(1))# then we agg
Out[742]: 
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
newkey                        
0       a  1  1  1  0  0  0  i
1       e  0  1  0  0  1  0  m
2       h  0  0  0  0  1  0  p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the `agg` funcs

```
s = lambda s: sum(int(k) for k in s)
d = {i: s for i in range(8)}
d.update({0: 'first', 7: 'first'})
df.groupby((df[0] == 'None').cumsum().shift().fillna(0)).agg(d)


    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0                               
0.0 a   1   1   1   1   0   0   i
1.0 e   0   1   0   1   1   0   m
2.0 h   0   0   0   0   1   0   p
```